# Issue with React useState 2D array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am facing strange behavior with useState. In the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-ellis-gjre7 I have 3 input fields, that change value if you click on them. The problem is with history state, that I log in console.

Expected behavior is, that as soon as you click on 1 of the boxes, it saves the state of all 3 boxes in history array, when we click another, it adds to history array new placements.

When clicking 1 box, it works correctly - "History 1" shows placement, and "History 2" and "History 3" are undefined.

But when we click 2nd box, it starts to act strange - It rewrites previously written "History 1", so now the content for "History 1" and "History 2" are the same. Strange, because all we do is concatenate new value to history array, but it overwrites the previous values.

Can anyone explain, why does it act in such a way?

Comment: Not a direct solution to a problem, but it took me some while to understand that `useReducer` is actually a better option for handling this kind of, a bit more complicated state structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 16, `newValue[event.value.id]` is getting mutated. Meaning, the same value is being updated and referenced in each element of `history`.

To reach the expected behaviour, the solution is to reference different values. This can be achieved by way of cloning.

See [this fork of your sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-ardinghelli-sltzz) for a practical example.

```
// Mutation.
newValue[event.target.id].value = "X";

// Cloning.
const targetId = event.target.id
newValue[targetId] = {...newValue[targetId], value: "X"};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write it as the following:

```
setHistory((prevHistory) => prevHistory.concat({ ...placements }));
```

Explanation:
I believe what you are doing is you're merging the previous state with the current one, from what I understand you want to contact the arrays -correct me if wrong -

Answer (score 0):

You have several things wrong.

1. You are using item.id as event.target.id, but you are updating base on placements' array index, which you will eventually end up with unforseen results.
2. You are updating history base on placements state, but when you are updating the history, the new placements might not be ready yet.

Here we will update your placements base on your item id instead of index. Then we update the history at the same time with the new placements.

```
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    // .map is commonly used in this type of situation to update the correct object in the array with new value.
    const newplacement = placements.map(item => item.id === parseInt(event.target.id) ? { ...item, value: 'X'} : item )
    
    setPlacements(newplacement);
    setHistory((prevHistory) => [...prevHistory, newplacement]);
  };
```

[my sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-stonebraker-uswo5?file=/src/App.js:339-611)